# Can we selectively generate XML documentation in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, swagger, documentation

I'm looking for perhaps an attribute or something that I could use to flag "I want this in my xml documentation", so like a whitelist.

The situation is that I wish to generate xml documentation for certain controllers to be displayed in swagger. However, many things should NOT be documented - especially auto-generated code such as CRM proxy types which contains hundreds of thousands of unwanted definitions.

I have enabled generate "Xml Documentation" in my project settings and I have disabled the warning about undocumented public items so automated builds complete in reasonable time but Visual Studio is generating an 8.1mb xml documentation file which Swagger is taking a long time to load. 90% of this is auto-generated proxy nonsense. I want instead to be able to say "document this file" in the controllers I care about - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way how to do it directly without any tool. This can be done with [VSdocman](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) (I'm the author of it). It can [generate your own XML doc file](https://www.helixoft.com/files/vsdocman/help/compileopt_3.html). You can then customize what to document, such as specific files/folders, regex filters for signatures and attributes, accessibility (public/private/...), special XML doc tag <compilewhen> and others.

Comment: This is not a free product.